# Does Thread execution differs within IDE and as exe application in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, codeblocks

I am new to C++ threading. I had developed an multi threaded application in c++11 using Code:blocks.

The application seams to execute and work perfectly (program start, divides up the task into threads, on completion they of task, then print info and then exit) from the Code-blocks.

But after generating the exe file using the code blocks, and on running the exe file seperately from command line, the program works as before until the task is completed, but on completion of all the task, threads fail to exit and proceed to next step.

Running the program within code:blocks and outside should be the same. I have added the divide task function below that carries out the threaded function. I have used the `moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue` for the function below.

```
void divide_task(){
    std::atomic<int> doneConsumers(0);
    std::thread threads[cores_aval];
    for (int i = 0; i != cores_aval; ++i) {
        threads[i] = std::thread([&]() {
            Item* item = new Read;
            do{
                while (con_read_q.try_dequeue(item)) {
                    //do something with hitem;
                    delete item;
                }
            }
            while (doneConsumers.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) + 1 == cores_aval);
        });
    }
}
```

**Update:** Thank you for replies. I had found the problem with the build option settings in the Code-blocks. One of the compiler flags in the release branch was affecting the final exe file,that reduced the file size by stripping of the symbols.

Comment: Perhaps there's a defect in your code. [Mcve]

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Timing between threads is likely different when running in the IDE and outside which xould expose race conditions more readily in one environment compared to the other.

Building with/without optimization will also change timings and can expose bugs as well.

In any case, without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) it's impossible to say what's wrong in your case, but my crystal ball says you likely have a data race in your code.

Are you sure this `while (con_read_q.try_dequeue(item)` is thread safe?

Comment: Yes i understand. i don't have a racing condition as i first load all the data that needs to be processed and then the processing stage starts. The queue has all the data it needs before the divide_task method is called.The moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue has the try_dequeue(item) which is a thread safe function.